# How to determine source of HTTP requests from a browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, reverse-proxy

I'm writing an HTTP reverse proxy for use with a specific application.  The proxy runs as an HttpHandler in IIS and applies a set of coded rules to find and rewrite URLs found in the HTTP responses from the application, so that requests made from the browser will go through the proxy server.

The application being proxied uses some HTML and CSS, but is primarily Javascript-based.  Using Fiddler, I can see requests the application makes from the browser, and this usually allows me to write a rule that can find and rewrite a particular class of URL reference, e.g. an HTML  tag or a Javascript url() call.

There are some cases, though, where I see a request being made in Fiddler, but can't find any reference to the URL anywhere in the HTML, Javascript or CSS that has been previously returned to the browser.  I'm looking for a tool or an approach that will help me isolate the origin of these requests at the source code level.  The browser I'm using is Firefox with Firebug installed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you provided specific examples of the requests. The only tools I would use are Fiddler (which you already have) and WireShark.

Comment: Many sites obfuscate their Javascript

Comment: Some of the Javascript is minified, but this shouldn't modify string literals.  My expectation is that if a request is made to GET /foo/bar.js, the string "/foo/bar" must appear somewhere in a response from the server, whether it be in HTML, Javascript, or even JSON.

Comment: Note that [Firebug is no longer developed](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/). Though the Firefox DevTools and the Chrome DevTools provide some info about the initiator of a network request in their Network panels.